# How can I add handler event into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, events, push

I have a element with an event which will be created 100 times in a `for` loop.
I wanna save the whole elements in an Array by an `push()` event and call the Array by another function but a error appears:
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined`

My Script:

```
var P = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    P.push($('.way')[i].getBoundingClientRect());
}
console.log(P);
```

Now I have understand that handler events cannot be included in an Array, but why?

What should i do to save the elements into an array?
Or is there other ways to save my handler event?

Comment: the js is fine, you just need more html .way-classed elements.

Comment: Is that element already in the DOM or are you creating it on the fly? Because in your example I see no evidence of the latter.

Comment: @amenadiel I dont know the code will broken if i try to get the element with event into the array and a error appears in the console.

Comment: I'm asking if you already have elements with ```className="way"``` in the document, or are you trying to create them inside the loop

Comment: oh, well jes i do I just want to save the element with the event.

Comment: it's obvisouly that you don't have enough 100 elements having class `way`.

Comment: @King King yes i have 100 Elements but this isn't important now.

Comment: You should set the jquery selection to a variable and get the array length, then make that part of the condition in the for loop. `var elements = $('.way'), arrLen = elements.length;  for (var i = 0; i < 100 && i < arrLen; i++){ etc... }`

Comment: Here's an example fiddle with 10 elements with class 'way': [http://jsfiddle.net/6Ps8z/](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ps8z/)

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using jQuery, you can use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
var P = [];

$('.way').each(function() {
    P.push(this.getBoundingClientRect());
});

console.log(P);
```

That way you can leave the count of how many items there are outside your script, should it change in the future.

Comment: i will give try in the future